# Rename integer named columns to string text

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I have a list of dataframes called: control1,control2,control3,control4,control5. I want to rename only the column named 10 (integer) for each dfs in the list.
I want to rename to this names: 'OPE_PROM_1','OPE_PROM_2','OPE_PROM_3','OPE_PROM_4','OPE_PROM_5'.
I tried this code

```
lista_controles=[control1,control2,control3,control4,control5]
for df in lista_controles:
    df.rename(columns={10:'OPE_PROM_'+df+''}, inplace=True)
```

But is not working. Is there any possible solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, Use:

```
lista_controles = [control1, control2, control3, control4, control5]
for i, df in enumerate(lista_controles, 1):
    df.rename(columns={10: f'OPE_PROM_{i}'}, inplace=True)
```